# Conditionally adding DOM elements with Reflex

Tags: haskell, frp, ghcjs, reflex

I have a function that receives a Dynamic and has to display a dom element which will contain a different kind of child depending on the value in the Dynamic. Is there a way to do such thing using Reflex and Reflex-Dom? The code would look like this if the value in the dynamic could be unwrapped by pattern matching:

```
myNode :: MonadWidget t m => Dynamic t Bool -> m (Event t ())
myNode (Dynamic True) = elClass "div" "foo" $
  elClass "div" "bar"
myNode (Dynamic False) = blank
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. The function [dyn](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-dom-0.3/docs/Reflex-Dom-Widget-Basic.html#v:dyn) can be used in those situations. Also see [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481916/how-can-i-branch-on-the-value-inside-a-reflex-dynamic).